# how to update each series field in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame which holds two columns like below:

```
    player_id    days
0     None        1
1     None        1
2     None        1
3     None        1
4     None        1
5     None        1
6     None        2
7     None        2
8     None        2
9     None        2
10    None        2
.
.
82    None        13
83    None        14
83    None        14
83    None        14
83    None        14
83    None        14
83    None        14
```

in output, I need to replace `None` with the id of players which is 1 to 11, have something like:

```
    player_id    days
0     1           1
1     2           1
2     3           1
3     4           1
4     5           1
5     6           1
6     7           2
7     8           2
8     9           2
9     10          2
10    11          2
11    1           2
12    2           2
13    3           2
14    4           2
.
.
82    5           13
83    6           14
83    7           14
83    8           14
83    9           14
83    10          14
83    11          14
```

this is my code:

```
for index in range(len(df)):
    for i in range(1, 11):
       df.iloc[index, 0] = i

print(df)
```

however I get the following dataframe:

```
    player_id    days
0     11           1
1     11           1
2     11           1
3     11           1
4     11           1
5     11           1
6     11           2
7     11           2
8     11           2
9     11           2
10    11           2
11    11           2
12    11           2
13    11           2
14    11           2
.
.
82    11           13
83    11           14
83    11           14
83    11           14
83    11           14
83    11           14
83    11           14
```

I also tried to add a new series as follows, but does not work:

```
for index in range(len(df)):
    for i in range(1, 11):
       df.iloc[index, 0] = pd.Series([i, df['day']], index=['player_id', 'day'])

print(df)
```

I have some doubt if editing a filed in dataframe is possible or not, I just skipped `itertuples` and `iterrows` to be able to edit this rows in an efficient way.

Comment: Something like `df["player_id"] = [i % 11 + 1 for i in range(len(df))]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `%` operator:

```
import numpy as np
df['player_id'] = 1 + np.arange(len(df))%11
df
```

output

```
    player_id   days
0   1   1
1   2   1
2   3   1
3   4   1
4   5   1
5   6   1
6   7   2
7   8   2
8   9   2
9   10  2
10  11  2
82  1   13
83  2   14
83  3   14
83  4   14
83  5   14
83  6   14
83  7   14
```

### Edit: using `index`

if the df's index (the first column in the output above) is not sequential and you want the same pattern but based on the index, then you can do

```
df['player_id'] = 1 + df.index%11
```

Comment: Your answer is good enough. Does this work when the ids are not in order? for example `1, 5,6, 11,12,13, 44..`?because player_id may change

Comment: @J2015 I am not really sure what you mean. what ids? the index? The solution is not using the index. If you want to label based on the index with the same pattern, see my edit

Comment: Thanks, I made a little mistake, your first solution is fine.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done as.

```
i=0
for index in range(len(df)):
        df.iloc[index, 0] = 1+i%11
        i+=1

print(df)
```

```
   player_id  days
0          1     1
1          2     1
2          3     1
3          4     1
4          5     1
5          6     1
6          7     1
7          8     1
8          9     1
9         10     1
10        11     1
11         1     2
12         2     2
13         3     2
14         4     2
15         5     2
16         6     2
17         7     2
18         8     2
19         9     2
20        10     2
21        11     2
22         1     3
23         2     3
24         3     3
25         4     3
26         5     3
27         6     3
28         7     3
29         8     3
30         9     3
31        10     3
32        11     3
```